# Batch export multiple datasets in a group within a (mesh/raster) layer as images?

Tags: qgis, raster, export, mesh

I have a mesh layer that contains a group with multiple datasets (dates). I'd like to export the visualization of each date together with another active raster layer (showing the basemap).

I could do this manually by selecting the dataset and then click on "Export Map to Image". This would take me ages though.

Any suggestions?

[image: Mesh layer with datasets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you can use the plugin Crayfish that has processing tool to export mesh layer to raster layer.
In the future release of QGIS 3.18, this processing will be natively support by QGIS.

Comment: Thank you! With Crayfish I can only convert one single dataset of the mesh layer to raster though (which takes a long time). If batch exporting images with raster layers is easier than with mesh layers, then I could convert my GRIB/NetCDF file with GDAL before importing it to QGIS. But how would I handle the batch export of multiple datasets within the raster layer later?

Comment: Nevermind. I just discovered the "export animation" feature in Crayfish which solves all my problems. This is awesome - thanks again!